# How to resize ImageView placeholder with picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

Picasso allows me to resize an image. Is there a mechanism for resizing the placeholder? The following is not sufficient. What am I missing?

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.imageview_holder).resize(200, 200).into(imageview);
```

Comment: You can't. Placeholders load from main thread directly. Picasso won't load them in background thread to perform these operations for you. Just resize it locally within your app.

Answer (score 5):

What I found that works for me is to resize the placeholder (and error image) directly with the ImageView using `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in the XML.  Then I can still use Picasso to resize and center the downloaded image.

Comment: This is correct answer. attr scaleType has no effect on loaded image if you resize it with picasso